# Docker COPY command doesn't seem to copy files to the WORKDIR

Tags: sql-server, linux, windows, docker, containers

I have been trying to Run SQL Server 2017 inside a Docker and also restore backup in it. 
I am able to run SQL server but it seems I am unable to successfully restore backup. 
I am not getting any errors. I tried to investigate with:

```
docker exec -it 44327a4ce101  sh
```

[image]

Files on my Desktop:

[image]

As you can see the tmp folder is empty inside docker container. But why?

**Dockerfile:**

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2017-latest AS BUILD
ENV ACCEPT_EULA=Y
ENV SA_PASSWORD=Pwd12345!

WORKDIR /tmp
COPY AdventureWorksLT2017.bak .
COPY restore-backup.sql .

RUN /opt/mssql/bin/sqlservr --accept-eula & sleep 10 \
    && /opt/mssql-tools/bin/sqlcmd -S localhost -U SA -P "Pwd12345!" -i /tmp/restore-backup.sql \
    && pkill sqlservr

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2017-latest AS RELEASE

ENV ACCEPT_EULA=Y
COPY --from=build /var/opt/mssql/data /var/opt/mssql/data
```

**restore-backup.sql**

```
RESTORE DATABASE [AdventureWorks] FROM DISK = '/tmp/AdventureWorksLT2017.bak'
WITH FILE = 1, 
MOVE 'AdventureWorksLT2012_Data' TO '/var/opt/mssql/data/AdventureWorks.mdf',
MOVE 'AdventureWorksLT2012_Log' TO '/var/opt/mssql/data/AdventureWorks.ldf',
NOUNLOAD, REPLACE, STATS = 5

GO

RESTORE FILELISTONLY FROM DISK = 'C:\Temp\docker\AdventureWorksLT2017.bak'
```

Comment: You copied the files into your build stage. Which stage did you build/run?

Comment: try `run cd /tmp` rather than `workdir /tmp`, or just copy directly to `/tmp` rather than `.`.

Comment: @BMitch the end stage.

Comment: @SoftwareEngineer you mean replace `COPY AdventureWorksLT2017.bak .
` with `COPY AdventureWorksLT2017.bak ./tmp
`

Comment: No, I mean replace it with `COPY AdventureWorksLT2017.bak /tmp` -- the difference is the `.` before the `/tmp`.

Comment: @SoftwareEngineer I have no idea what changed but all of a sudden I am not getting `Sqlcmd: Error: Microsoft ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server : Login timeout expired.` when building image

Comment: @SoftwareEngineer changing it to /temp gives me that error. I think.

Answer (score 1):

You are running a multi stage build. Each stage builds a separate image, and you can copy artifacts between stages with an explicit copy command. It does not merge multiple images together.

Therefore, the files you have copied into your BUILD stage, that you do not copy into the RELEASE stage are not expected to be in the containers based off that RELEASE image.

Comment: I guess you are right. I can see both the files when I investigate the image that is created after `COPY restore-backup.sql `  
My problems are getting compounded. I changed `COPY AdventureWorksLT2017.bak .` to  `COPY AdventureWorksLT2017.bak /tmp` and not I keep getting ` Login timeout expired.` even if I change it back to how it was. I

Comment: @SamuraiJack I don't have any experience with Windows containers or MS SQL, so I can't be any help there. Just wanted to help you understand the original question asked.

Comment: It's solved.  I was running the container with ` docker run -e "ACCEPT_EULA=Y" -e "SA_PASSWORD=Pwd12345!"-p 11433:1433 -d mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2017-latest`  I  then ran it with ` docker run -e "ACCEPT_EULA=Y" -e "SA_PASSWORD=Pwd12345!" -p 11433:1433 -d restored-db`

Comment: I still do not know why  changing `COPY AdventureWorksLT2017.bak . `   to `COPY AdventureWorksLT2017.bak /tmp ` would cause sql login timeout. It gets resolved on its own after an hour or so automatically.

Comment: thanks for your help . For explaining why that folder is empty. +1